# React and ApolloClient: Network error: forward(...).subscribe is not a function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I'm building a React + GraphQL app and having a strange issue. The code below sets up an ApolloClient, adds a bearer token, then tries to fetch by id.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const id = this.props.match.params.id;
  if (id !== 'new') {
    const authLink = setContext(async (_, {headers}) => {
      const token = await this.props.auth.getAccessToken();

      // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
      return {
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
        }
      }
    });

    const client = new ApolloClient({
      link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
    });

    client.query({
      query: gql`{
          query GetPoints(id: Int) {
              pointsGet(id: $id) {
                  date,
                  alcohol,
                  exercise,
                  diet,
                  notes
              }
          }
      }
      `,
      variables: {id: id}
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.setState({points: result.data.points});
    });
  } else {
    console.log('new!');
  }
}
```

This code results in the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: forward(...).subscribe is not a function
    at new ApolloError (ApolloError.js:43)
    at QueryManager.js:327
    at QueryManager.js:762
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at QueryManager.js:761
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at QueryManager../node_modules/apollo-client/core/QueryManager.js.QueryManager.broadcastQueries (QueryManager.js:754)
    at QueryManager.js:254
```

Here's my code (without parameters) that works fine:

```
async componentDidMount() {
   const user = await this.props.auth.getUser();
   this.setState({user});

   const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
     const token = await this.props.auth.getAccessToken();

     // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
     return {
       headers: {
         ...headers,
         authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
         'x-forwarded-user': user ? JSON.stringify(user) : ''
       }
     }
   });

   const client = new ApolloClient({
     link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
     cache: new InMemoryCache()
   });

   client.query({
     query: gql`
         {
           points {
               id,
               user {
                   id,
                   lastName
               }
               date,
               alcohol,
               exercise,
               diet,
               notes
           }
         }
     `
   })
   .then(result => {
     console.log(result);
     this.setState({points: result.data.points});
   });
 }
```

Here's a list of libraries I'm using:

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same bug, fixed it by using this set of libraries

```
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { setContext } from "apollo-link-context";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
```